# Benefits of power leveling

Tags: neverwinter

Are there any (dis)advantages of powerleveling a character?

I have seen some foundry quests that allow powerleveling, but I am not sure if this is worth doing.  Will the game just keep pace with me, will it let me actually be more powerful, or will it break the  balance and actually make it more difficult?

Comment: They nerfed foundry experience point gains yesterday because of the exploitation.  That being said, the main questline only takes about 30 hours to get max, if you know what you are doing.

Answer (score 1):

After level 30 the difficulty of Neverwinter jumps up.  However, unless you are rushing to end game, I don't think power leveling is really going to benefit you.

Comment: Can you include in your answer why you think that? Giving reasons for what you think is much more informative to the reader than just knowing that somewhere in the Internet, someone thinks something.

Answer (score 1):

Coming to this much later in the development of the game, I'd say if you power level your first character, you'll miss out on a ton of content and story-line and the many parallel quests that go on. The writing is well done, and there's even a ton of additional lore to enjoy (although a separate lore reader app for mobile might be nice... it really is a lot of text).

Even without power leveling, I've breezed by some content because of leveling beyond it very quickly.

For secondary characters -- since each free account can have up to 3 -- the story is different. However, knowing that the end game content takes a lot of time with daily and weekly quests, and a bit of grinding, it all depends on how much you enjoy "the grind" once you cap each character.